# DRF - The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pytorch

I'm trying to save my update serialize. The predict field is changed to the value predicted by Inference code(Image Classfication model).

But I get the error:

AttributeError at /predict/product/1/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `image` on serializer `ProductSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'image'.

> AttributeError at /predict/product/1/
> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `image` on serializer `ProductSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'image'.

I checked migrations.

- Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Product
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ProductSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
#from .inference_code import predict
from .apps import ProductConfig 
import json

class ProductListAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class  = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    
    def get(self, request): 
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        print(queryset)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self,requset):
        serializer= ProductSerializer(
            data=requset.data)
        
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    
    
class ProductPredictAPI(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

            
    def get(self, requset, pk, format=None):
        product=self.get_object(pk)
        serializer=ProductSerializer(product)
        
        img_name=serializer.data['image'].split('/')
        image_name=str(img_name[-1])
        predictions=ProductConfig.model.predict(image_name)
        
        
        serializer=ProductSerializer(serializer.data,data=predictions,many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def delete(self,request,pk,format=None):
        product=self.get_object(pk)
        product.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

- Serializers.py

```py
#product/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer) :
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    predict= serializers.CharField(max_length=70)
    class Meta :
        model = Product      
        fields = ('id','image','predict')
```

- models.py

```py
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    predict = models.CharField(max_length=70,null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="media/default.jpg", null=True, blank=True,upload_to="uploads")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.predict
```

-Inference.py (Image classification)

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from tqdm import tqdm

import os
import random
import matplotlib as plt
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, accuracy_score
import time
from typing import Tuple, Sequence, Callable
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from torchvision import models


def img_load(path):
    img = cv2.resize(path, (16, 16))
    return img


class Custom_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, 
                 img_paths, 
                 labels, 
                 mode='train',
                 transforms= Sequence[Callable]
            ) -> None:
        self.img_paths = img_paths
        self.labels = labels
        self.mode=mode
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_paths)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img = self.img_paths[idx]
        if self.mode=='train':
            augmentation = random.randint(0,2)
            if augmentation==1:
                img = img[::-1].copy()
            elif augmentation==2:
                img = img[:,::-1].copy()
        if self.mode=='test':
            pass
#tv.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
        img = Image.fromarray(img) # NumPy array to PIL image
        img = img.convert("RGB")

        if self.transforms is not None:
            img = self.transforms(img)        
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return img, label
        
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.model = models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=False)
        self.linear=nn.Linear(in_features=1000,out_features=88)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x


class PredictModel():
    def predict(self,file_name=None):
        if file_name==None:
            return { "answer" : "error" }
        else:
            device = torch.device('cuda')
            path="/workspace/drf_disease/media/uploads/{}".format(file_name)
            test_png = cv2.imread(path)
            test_imgs = img_load(test_png)

            transforms_test = transforms.Compose([
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize(
                    [0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                    [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
                )
            ])

            train_y = pd.read_csv('/workspace/drf_disease/product/input/train_df.csv')

            train_labels = train_y["label"]

            label_unique = sorted(np.unique(train_labels))
            label_unique = {key:value for key,value in zip(label_unique, range(len(label_unique)))}

            # Test
            batch_size = 1

            test_dataset = Custom_dataset(np.array(test_imgs), np.array(["tmp"]*len(test_imgs)), mode='test',transforms=transforms_test)
            test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)

            device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
            model = Network().to(device)
            #model.load_state_dict(torch.load('./input/models/test_model.pth'), strict=False)

            model.eval()
            f_pred = []

            with torch.no_grad():
                for batch in (test_loader):
                    x = torch.tensor(batch[0], dtype = torch.float32, device = device)
                    pred = model(x)
                    f_pred.extend(pred.argmax(1).detach().cpu().numpy().tolist())


            label_decoder = {val:key for key, val in label_unique.items()}
            f_result = [label_decoder[result] for result in f_pred]
            return {"answer" : f_result[0]}
```

How can i solve this problem?